# Running Universal Windows test project on a remote device - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: deviceID

Tags: uwp, remote-debugging

I'm trying to run a Universal Windows test project on a remote device, and am getting the following error in the Tests output:

> ------ Discover test started ------
>   ========== Discover test finished: 2 found (0:00:00.4614566) ==========
>   ------ Run test started ------ Updating the layout...
>
> Checking whether required frameworks are installed...
>
> Registering the application to run from layout...
>
> Deployment complete (0:00:01.854). Full package name:
>   "5dc015bc-0c65-416c-99d6-6ec6d52e63e3_1.0.0.0_x86__bme28qw9yyzpj"
>
> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: deviceID
>   ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:09.5471841) ==========

If I manually deploy and run the test project, it runs (well, it doesn't crash), but the tests don't actually run.

I'm developing on Windows 8.1 and deploying to a Windows 10 Surface Pro.

Anyone else seen this and have a solution?

Comment: Just ran into the same problem deploying to Xbox One from Windows 10.